# Car Seat Placement

Tags: driving, new-jersey

I have been told that in most states, children of a certain size must be placed in a child car seat and that seat must be attached in the rear auto seat. I am most interested in New Jersey.

1. Is this just a suggestion or are there any state laws mandating this?
2. Would this law apply to two-seat cars like the Chevy Corvette or Mazda Miata?

Comment: Yes, there are state laws. A rear-facing infant seat cannot go in a seat that has an automatic airbag that can't be turned off--like a front seat. Most newer cars have a weight sensor that will turn off the airbag. What state?

Comment: @mkennedy ..........New Jersey..........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the [relevant text](http://www.nj.gov/lps/hts/childseats/childseats_newlaw.html) from New Jersey's government:

**Legislation - P.L. 2015, c.50**

> The following recommendations will provide the safest way to transport your child according to the American Academy of Pediatrics and the National Highway Traffic Safety Administration (NHTSA). Additionally it will ensure compliance to the New Jersey Child Passenger Restraint Law. (Title 39:3-76.2a)
>
> Any child under the age of 8 years old and a height of 57 inches shall be secured as follows in the rear seat of a motor vehicle:
>
> a. A child under the age of 2 years and 30 pounds shall be secured in a rear-facing seat equipped with a 5-point harness.
>
> b. A child under the age of 4 years and 40 pounds shall be secured as described in (a) until they reach the upper limits of the rear-facing seat, then in a forward-facing child restraint equipped with a 5-point harness.
>
> c. A child under the age of 8 and a height of 57 inches shall be secured as described in (a) or (b) until they reach the upper limits of the rear-facing or forwardfacing seat, then in a belt positioning booster seat.
>
> d. A child over 8 years of age or 57 inches in height must be properly secured by a seat belt.
>
> If there are no rear seats, the child shall be secured as described above in the front seat except that no child shall be secured in a rear-facing seat in the front seat of any vehicle that is equipped with an active passenger-side airbag. The aforementioned is acceptable if the airbag is de-activated.